# Displaying Twitter User Account Tweets on Android Application Screen

Tags: android, android-intent, android-listview, android-facebook, android-twitter

I have a requirement to display Twitter Tweets of a particular User Account on Android Screen?

Could any one Tell me procedure?

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to sign up to twitter and get an api key from https://dev.twitter.com/apps. Follow the steps there for signup. You probably also want a widget which will help you display the widgets in html - sample code for this is all over the web, just do a search for embedding a twitter widget. If you need native android functionality (not just web) you want to investigate a framework like Phonegap.